# Sorting an array using only first and last index of the array

Tags: arrays, c

I have a function that generates a random array, and I have another function which prints the generated array.

The issue is that in the print function I only have the address of the first & last index of the array.

How can I can print the whole array using only the addreses of the first element and the last element?

Here is the function which is required to print the array :

```
void printArray(int *s_ptr, int *e_ptr);
```

And here is my main function :

```
int randInRange(int min, int max) { return min + rand() % (max - min + 1); }
int main(void) {
    int array[MaxSize];

    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i=0 ; i<MaxSize ; i++) {
        array[i] = (int) randInRange(MIN, MAX);
    }
    printArray(&array[0], &array[MaxSize-1]);

    printArray(&array[0], &array[MaxSize-1]);
}
```

Comment: You don't need to cast the return value of `randInRange` to `(int)`. The function returns an `int`, so no casting required. And if you don't *have* to cast, don't cast. With some code changes this might introduce some bugs that are hard to identify.

Comment: Side note: Instead of writing `&array[0]`, you can simply write `array`. When you write `array`, it will automatically [decay](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/12149471) to a pointer to the first element.

Comment: Note: `randInRange()` may not return values in the whole `[min ... max]` range when `max - min > RAND_MAX`.

Answer (score 4):

There is not much to it. Just increment the pointer. → `p++`

```
void printArray(int *s_ptr, int *e_ptr) {
    for (int *p = s_ptr; p <= e_ptr; p++) {
        printf("%d\n", *p);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> *How can I can print the whole array using only the addreses of the first element and the last element?*

To start with, couple of things about array that you should know (if not aware of):

1. An array is a collection of elements of the same type placed in **contiguous memory locations**.
2. An array name, when used in an expression, **will convert to pointer to first element of that array** (there are few *exceptions* to this rule).

E.g.:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    // Hardcoding the size of array (5) in for loop condition
    // Note that you can use expression - sizeof (arr) / sizeof (arr[0]) to get size 
    // of array instead of hardcoding it.
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        printf ("%d\n", arr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here the `arr[i]`, in `printf()` statement, will be interpreted as<sup>1)</sup> -

```
(*((arr) + (i)))
```

and, in this expression, the `arr` will be converted to address of first element of array `arr` i.e. `&arr[0]` and to that address the value of `i` will be added and the resultant pointer will be then dereferenced to get the value at that location. Since, the array element placed in contiguous memory locations, adding `0`, `1`, `2`, .., and so on, to the address of first element of array and dereferencing it will give the value of `1`<sup>st</sup>, `2`<sup>nd</sup>, `3`<sup>rd</sup>, .., and so on, elements of array respectively.

Now, you are passing the address of first and last element of given array to function `printArray()`. Using the address of first element we can get the value of all the elements of array. The only thing we need is the size of array in `printArray()` function.

From C Standard#6.5.6p9 *[emphasis added]*

> **When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object**, or one past the last element of the array object; **the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two array elements**. The size of the result is implementation-defined, and **its type (a signed integer type) is ptrdiff_t** defined in the <stddef.h> header.

The two argument to `printArray()` function are pointer to first and last element of same array. As you have shown in question, the `printArray()` is called like this:

```
printArray(&array[0], &array[MaxSize-1]);
                  ^          ^^^^^^^^^
                  |              |
               subscript      subscript
               of first       of last
               element        element
```

When we subtract them the result we get is the difference of the subscripts of the first and last elements of that array. That means, in `printArray()` function() this

```
e_ptr - s_ptr
```

will give result same as

```
MaxSize-1 - 0 = MaxSize-1
```

if we add one to this result, we will get size of array

```
MaxSize-1 + 1 = MaxSize
```

Now, we know how to get size of array in `printArray()` and also know how to get the value of all elements of array using the address of first element. Lets implement `printArray()`:

```
void printArray(int *s_ptr, int *e_ptr) {
    // To get the size of array subtract e_ptr and s_ptr and add 1
    ptrdiff_t size = e_ptr - s_ptr + 1;

    for (ptrdiff_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        printf ("%d\n", *((s_ptr) + (i)));
    }
}
```

This will output all the elements of array, provided `s_ptr` should be pointer to first element and `e_ptr` should be pointer to last element of same array. This `*((s_ptr) + (i))` looks bit cluttered. As per the definition of subscript operator `[]`<sup>1)</sup>, `*((s_ptr) + (i))` is same as `s_ptr[i]`. So, the `printf()` statement in the for loop can be written as - `printf ("%d\n", s_ptr[i]);`.

Alternatively, you can use the pointer of type same as type of array element. Assign the first element address to this pointer and dereferencing it to get value at that location. Increment the pointer and print till it reaches to address of last element of array. The implementation is shown in *@Cheatah* post.

---

1). C11 standard##6.5.2.1p2

> The definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to (*((E1)+(E2)))